# Moodle api list all cohorts

Tags: api, rest, moodle

Im looking to get all cohorts, i can get the info if i have the id but i want all the cohorts names and ids. Please let me know if theres a way to do this. Thanks in advance

```
$functionname = 'core_cohort_get_cohorts';
$cohortIDS = array( '1' );
$data_string = http_build_query(array('cohortids' => $cohortIDS));

$utoken = 'mytoken';

$adduser = 'yoururl/webservice/rest/server.php?               wstoken='.$utoken.'&wsfunction='.$functionname.'&moodlewsrestformat=json';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$adduser);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo '<pre>';
 print_r(json_decode($server_output));
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add more method to core_cohort to get all cohort as the following:
In the cohort/externallib.php, add more method:

```
public static function get_all_cohorts(){
    global $DB;
    $cohortids = $DB->get_records('cohort', null, null, 'id');
    $arrids = array();
    foreach($cohortids as $id){
        $arrids[] = $id->id;
    }
    return (new core_cohort_external())->get_cohorts($arrids);
}
```

In addition, you have to register this webservice called 'core_cohort_get_all_cohorts' to call this webservice from outside. Please tell me if you have further question.